# Calling Jsp page from controller in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring MVC. I've contoller which catches an exception, after catching the exception i want to redirect to error.jsp page and display the exception message (ex.getMessage()). I don't want to use Spring's Exception Handler rather i have to redirect to error.jsp programmatically.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "http/exception", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String exception2()
{
    try{
        generateException();
    }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        handleException();
    }
    return "";
}

private void generateException(){
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();      
}

private void handleException(){

    // what should go here to redirect the page to error.jsp
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're returning `String` from your method; the standard in Spring MVC is for methods annotated with `@RequestMapping` to return a `ModelAndView`, even if you're not using Spring's Exception Handler. As far as I know you can't send your client to error.jsp without returning a `ModelAndView` somewhere. If you need help understanding the basic idea of Spring controllers, I found [this tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-create-hello-world-application-spring-3-mvc/) showing how to create a simple "Hello World" application in Spring MVC, and it has a good example of a simple Spring controller.

If you want your method to return an error page if it encounters an exception, but otherwise return a normal page, I would do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "http/exception", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView exception2()
{
    ModelAndView modelAndview;
    try {
        generateException();
        modelAndView = new ModelAndView("success.jsp");
    } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        modelAndView = handleException();
    }
    return modelAndView;
}

private void generateException(){
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();      
}

private ModelAndView handleException(){
     return new ModelAndView("error.jsp");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Edward. You're right. It should've not been String and this approch will work. Thanks for your response